# Is the relative moduli space of semi-stable sheaves on families of curves fine

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, moduli-spaces, coherent-sheaves, representable-functors

Let $\pi:X \to B$ be a family of smooth, projective curves. Fix coprime integers $r,d$. Denote by $\mathcal{M}(r,d)$ the relative moduli functor corresponding to rank $r$, degree $d$, semi-stable sheaves on $X$ flat over $B$. It seems from the book "Relative  moduli spaces of semi-stable sheaves on families of curves" by Jens Thomas Alexander Lang, Theorem 6.10, this functor is representable. But, this book is not downloadable and I cannot see the entire proof.

Is this statement true (i.e., is $\mathcal{M}(r,d)$ representable if $r$ and $d$ are coprime)? If so, can anyone tell me if this book is available online or suggest an alternate reference. A sketch of the proof is also fine.

Comment: The answer depends on whether or not $\pi$ has a degree $1$ zero-cycle.  If, for instance, $\pi$ has a section $\sigma$, then there does exist *a* universal sheaf.  This holds, more generally, if there exists a finite collection of closed subschemes of $X$ that are flat of relative dimension $0$ over $B$ and whose relative degrees over $B$ are coprime (i.e., if there exists a degree $1$ zero-cycle).  However, there are families where there is no degree $1$ zero-cycle and there is no universal family (that already happens if $r$ equals $1$).

Comment: Here is an example with no degree $1$ zero-cycle and no universal sheaf.  For $Y=\mathbb{P}^2$, the parameter space of conics in $Y$ is a projective space, $\mathbb{P}^5=\mathbb{P}H^0(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y(2))$.  Let $B\subset \mathbb{P}^5$ be the dense open subset parameterizing smooth plane conics.  Let $X\subset B\times Y$ be the universal family of smooth plane conics.  Let $r$ equal $1$, and let $d$ equal $1$.  The moduli stack over $B$ of flat families of rank $1$, degree $1$ invertible sheaves on pullbacks of $X$ has a coarse moduli space that is $B$.  There is no universal sheaf.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you. Could you please suggest a text where I can read about this relative case. I could not find much in the book by Huybrechts and Lehn. Or, may be you could elaborate a bit more, why the existence of a degree $1$ zero-cycle determines the answer to the question.

Comment: I am not sure what is the best reference.  I believe that the article of Max Lieblich for the Salt Lake City volume might discuss this (but I am not sure).